# Modelo en keras sin bias

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Estoy tratando de hacer un modelo simple en Keras y cuando hago `model.summary` obtengo 12 parametros

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=5))
model.summary()
```

Obteniendo

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 12
Trainable params: 12
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

De ellos 10 son parte del tensor que multiplica la entrada (dimension 5) y las neuronas de la capa (2). Los otros dos parámetros son las *bias* que se adicionan automáticamente en la capa *Dense*.

Mi pregunta es. ¿Cómo hago para que el modelo no tenga *bias*, o sea, que conste de sólo 10 parámetros?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba el parametro `use_bias`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=5, use_bias = False))
model.summary()
```

Que nos da:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________
```

---

Que entiendo es lo que buscas.